# Query parity or geth to get total ethereum produced?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

How do I query geth or parity to get the total coins ever mined/in circulation.
On bitcoind or any other coin based on btc core source its easy to achieve with a command line.

Something similar for ethereum?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geth attach`

Then in the JS console:

`console.log(web3.sha3('totalSupply()').substring(0,10))`